# How do I configure VS Code to auto-complete / closing of HTML elements in PHP files like Adobe Brackets does?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, adobe, adobe-brackets

Adobe just slapped me with horrible news saying they will end support for the Brackets Editor and we need to switch to VS Code.

I wasted an hour already just to have auto-closing of tags to work.

Here is a video explaining exactly what I want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRGP2.jpg

I want to be able to have auto-close work for HTML elements in a PHP file like it does without issue on Adobe Brackets.

Answer (score -1):

VS Code has a lot of extension for this kind of need. I personally use HTML Snippets.

Just navigate to extensions tab, search HTML Snippets then click install.

Please check this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html) for your reference. You can find some extension which could cater your needs.